# Can't UPDATE MySQL in Php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with PHP and MYSQL.
I'm trying to Update a row with this code:

```
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$name=mysql_real_escape_string( $name);
$target = 'photo/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
$target=mysql_real_escape_string($target);
$nick=$_POST['nick'];
$nick=mysql_real_escape_string($nick);
mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET Name='$name', Image='$target' WHERE Nickname='$nick' ;")or die(mysql_error());
```

Now, I can edit Name, but I can't Image!! It's so strange!
Html is correct!

__UPDATE

I use mysql_real_escape_string for all of them.
I checked the column name.

__UPDATE

I updated the code, It don't return any mysql_error

Comment: Maybe surname contains an apostrophe ? !

Comment: Bobby Tables springs to mind here

Comment: 1) `$nick` doesn't seem to exist. 2) you're vulnerable to the easiest injection attacks 3) `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead

Comment: Where did you learn to write MySQL code like this? Nothing about this is even remotely a good idea. `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Use bind parameters http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Please post the error you are getting when you execute this query. Also check that the column name matches with the query you are performing.

Comment: Even if you are using mysql_real_escape_string your code isn't safe. Use mysqli with prepared statements. Use php error-reporting. Post errors here. If using $_POST, always check them with if(!isset). NEVER trust user input.

Comment: I Updated my code, I tried to use PDO but it doesn't work! And I don't receive any Mysql_error, but I can't edit it

Comment: you now have `target` but no `surname`! Which one is not getting updated??

Comment: If I get a SQL statement that won't execute, I echo it out and see what it created. Then try and run it in a server console directly.

Comment: If you dont get an error, them maybe your code never reaches the query part on some cases. 

Check the error log for other errors, or echo out a number after each line with the variable name, to see where the parsing stops and whats the variable's actual value. e.g
$name=$_POST['Name'];echo( "name is:". $name);
$name=mysql_real_escape_string( $name);echo( "name is :". $name);

Comment: I checked it yet! And target isn't null

Comment: How about other variables. Do as i said, add echo statements for every single line leading up to that query. 
see how many lines echo their variables out, and if they are what you think they are.
also , echo out the query itself to double check.
    $nick=mysql_real_escape_string($nick);
    echo "UPDATE Users SET Name='$name', Image='$target' WHERE Nickname='$nick' ;";
    mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET Name='$name', Image='$target' WHERE Nickname='$nick' ;")or die(mysql_error());

if you echo out the query, copy paste it into phpMyAdmin/ mysql console and run it manually. See if that works

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, mysql_* is deprecated( as of PHP version 5.5.0) ...but if you already have built some of your project using it then you can keep using it, But you should never send user posted values directly into the database. escape them first.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['Name'] );
$surname= mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['Surname'] );
```

Comment: OP has already said _"I use mysql_real_escape_string for all of them"_

Comment: Looks like he edited his post while i was typing. No problem :)

Comment: @Philipp why should this be missing? I use an external script to sanitize all user inputs (get and post) in addition to prepared statements. This is just the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use the syntax:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
```

not

```
$_FILES['file']['name']
```

to get the original name of the file on the client machine.
See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

**EDIT**
If you are seeing values in your variables, but the sql is not working as you think it should, then you need to debug it.

Change your code slightly so you have:

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE Users SET Name='$name', Image='$target' WHERE Nickname='$nick' ;");
die($update_sql);
mysql_query($update_sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

and check what is in `$update_sql` (adding it to your question would be useful). If there is a problem, fix it and test again. Once you're happy it should work, comment out the `die` line.

Comment: No, target value return correctly, the problem is with the query